# Get the pkcs#12 certificate from a foreign app on an unrooted phone to use it in packet capture?

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, pkcs#12

I have a toy drone that communicates with an android app over wifi.
My goal is to send the signals from a raspberry pi, to control the drone from there.
To intercept the data I tried using the app `packet capture`.
It yielded no data, as the app seems to use a pkcs#12 ssl certificate.
How do I get the pkcs#12 certificate from the app to use it in packet capture?

Comment: How will getting the certificate help in packet capture?

Comment: You can import it into packet capture.